# Bit Test (BT) in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I'm using bt to test if certain bits are set or unset in assembly. My code looks like this:

```
#define bv  %eax   //just renaming reg to make reading easier
#define bit %edx   //rename reg
/*
 * bitIsSetBV(unsigned int *bv, unsigned int bit)
 * this function returns 0 if bit at location bit is not set
 * it returns 1 if it is set
 */

.text
.global bitIsSetBV

bitIsSetBV:
movl 4(%esp), bv   //make room on stack for bv
movl 8(%esp), bit  //make room on stack for bit

bt bit, (bv)       //if bv[bit] is 0, set CF to 0, else, set CF to 1
jc bitSet          // if CF is 1, jump to bitSet
jnc bitNotSet      // if CF is 0, jump to bitNotSet

bitNotSet:
movl $0, bv        //return 0, bit is not set
jmp Done           // jump to Done

bitSet:
movl $1, bv         // return 1, bit is set
jmp Done           // jump to Done

Done:
ret                //end of code
```

Tester:

> ```
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 0) == 1); // 0001
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 1) == 0);
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 2) == 0);
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 3) == 0);
>
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 4) == 0); // 1110
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 5) == 1);
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 6) == 1);
>   assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 7) == 1);
> ```

My code works for bit =0-5, but at bit=6, it does not. Why is that? I'm sure it's something I'm misunderstanding about bit level operations.

Comment: `just renaming reg to make reading easier` that comment is interesting. I didn't even look at those two lines and looked at your code and wondered how `BT` was using a couple memory operands. Maybe I am getting old but those two defines made the code much harder to follow lol

Comment: You don't show us the test C code that defines `bv` so we don't know how it is actually defined and assigned. Although your code is inefficient this redundancy is completely unnecessary: `jnc bitNotSet`. Remove that line since you already tested for carry being set on the instruction before so if it falls through it must not be set. It will just fall through to the next instruction which happens to be the code for `bitNotSet`. `jmp Done` just before the label `Done` can also be removed since you are jumping to the next instruction.

Comment: `movl 4(%esp), bv   //make room on stack for bv` The comment on that code doesn't match. The stack already holds the values, you are copying them into registers. You aren't `making room` for them on the stack.

Comment: I would also hope you are compiling/assembling your program as 32-bit and not 64-bit given the code shown.

Comment: You should produce a minimal test program so people can see the code you are using to call your function. Tell us if you are 64-bit or 32-bit, and let us know what command lines you use to compile/link your files. I can only guess the issue you are having is in your _C_ code (_bv_ isn't the value you think it is) or you are trying to run a function that uses 32-bit calling convention in a 64-bit _C_ program. I'd expect it to fault than to give incorrect output.

Comment: `bt bit, (bv)       //if bv[bit] is 0, set CF to 0, else, set CF to 1` How is this `bv[bit]`?  This is just dereferencing `bv` and testing the bit at `bit`...  How are you defining `bv` in the C code?

Comment: Instead of branching on the carry flag, use `xor %eax,%eax / bt / setc %al`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a response to your question, but not necessarily an answer with a solution. Although your assembly code is inefficient, when I first saw it I didn't see any logical flaw to it, so I assume the problem is not in your assembly code but somewhere in your *C* code. I did make a request last night for you to provide your *C* code, but there was no follow up.

I took the redundant jumps and branches out of the assembly code below, but your original code should have worked. I put this in an assembly file called `isbitset.S`:

```
#define bv  %eax   //just renaming reg to make reading easier
#define bit %edx   //rename reg
/*
 * bitIsSetBV(unsigned int *bv, unsigned int bit)
 * this function returns 0 if bit at location bit is not set
 * it returns 1 if it is set
 */

.text
.global bitIsSetBV

bitIsSetBV:
movl 4(%esp), bv   //make room on stack for bv
movl 8(%esp), bit  //make room on stack for bit

bt bit, (bv)       //if bv[bit] is 0, set CF to 0, else, set CF to 1
jc bitSet          // if CF is 1, jump to bitSet

bitNotSet:
movl $0, bv        //return 0, bit is not set
jmp Done           // jump to Done

bitSet:
movl $1, bv         // return 1, bit is set

Done:
ret                //end of code
```

I recommend the suggestion Peter Cordes made in the comment for making the code more efficient. Since I think the concern is in the test program I'm more concerned with how it was being called. I created this simple test program in *C* called `bittest.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>

extern int bitIsSetBV(unsigned int *bv, unsigned int bit);

int main()
{
  unsigned int a = 0xe1; /* which is binary 11100001 */
  unsigned int *bv = &a;

  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 0) == 1); /* 0001 */
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 1) == 0);
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 2) == 0);
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 3) == 0);

  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 4) == 0); /* 1110 */
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 5) == 1);
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 6) == 1);
  assert(bitIsSetBV(bv, 7) == 1);

  return 0;
}
```

I assemble, compile and link the code to a program called `bittest` with these commands:

```
gcc -m32 -c isbitset.S -o isbitset.o
gcc -m32 bittest.c isbitset.o -o bittest
```

Alternatively you could have done it this way too:

```
gcc -m32 bittest.c isbitset.S -o bittest
```

I run it like this:

```
./bittest
```

The `-m32` ensures that you are generating a 32-bit executable. This can make a big difference if you are compiling this on a 64-bit system which defaults to [64-bit System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) used by Linux. You wrote your assembler code using 32-bit calling convention so it won't work if called from a *C* program compiled as 64-bit.

In this case the code doesn't generate any assertions which does mean the bits were as I expected.

This answer also provides a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and is an example of how you could create a question that people could test.